# Write performance scala immutable collections

Tags: scala, collections, seq

Quick question. I'm currently designing some database queries to extract reasonably large, but not massive datasets into memory, say approximately 10k-100k records.

So far I've been testing loading these resultsets into a scala.collection.immutable.Seq and have discovered it seems to take an incredibly long time to build the collection. Whereas if I change to a Vector or List the write into memory takes fractions of a second.

MY question is therefore why is Seq so slow in this case? If so in what cases would using Seq be more appropriate than Vector?

Thanks

Comment: Performance characteristics of collection types: http://www.scala-lang.org/docu/files/collections-api/collections_40.html The default `Seq` is `List`.

Comment: Use builder: `Seq.newBuilder` or `IndexedSeq.newBuilder`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It would help if you'd post the relevant snippet and which operations you call on the sequence -- `immutable.Seq` is represented using a `List` (see https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/v2.10.2/src/library/scala/collection/immutable/Seq.scala#L42). My guess is that you've been using `:+` on the `immutable.Seq`, which under the hood appends to the end of the list by copying it (probably giving you quadratic overall performance), and when you switched to using `immutable.List` directly, you've been attaching to the beginning using `::` (giving you linear performance).

Since `Seq` is just a `List` under the hood, you should use it when you attach to the beginning of the sequence -- the cons operator `::` only creates a one node and links it to the rest of the list, which is as fast as it can get when it comes to immutable data structures. Otherwise, if you add to the end, and you insist on immutability, you should use a `Vector` (or the upcoming `Conc` lists!).

If you would like a validation of these claims, see this [link](http://lampwww.epfl.ch/~prokopec/npc-chara/report/#config=%7B%22filterConfig%22%3A%7B%22curves%22%3A%5B%22-1%22%2C%220%22%2C%221%22%2C%222%22%5D%2C%22order%22%3A%5B%22param-size%22%2C%22param-par%22%2C%22date%22%5D%2C%22filters%22%3A%5B%5B%22100000%22%2C%22300000%22%2C%22500000%22%2C%22900000%22%2C%221000000%22%2C%221500000%22%2C%223000000%22%2C%225000000%22%2C%229000000%22%2C%2210000000%22%2C%2215000000%22%2C%2230000000%22%2C%2250000000%22%2C%2290000000%22%2C%22150000000%22%5D%2C%5B%221%22%5D%2C%5B%221371223988000%22%5D%5D%7D%2C%22chartConfig%22%3A%7B%22type%22%3A0%2C%22showCI%22%3Afalse%7D%7D) where the performance of the two operations is compared using ScalaMeter -- lists are 8 times faster than vectors when you add to the beginning.

However, the most appropriate data structure should be either an `ArrayBuffer` or a `VectorBuilder`. These are mutable data structures that resize dynamically and if you build them using `+=` you will get a reasonable performance. This is assuming that you are not storing primitives.

Comment: I have not found a `VectorBuffer`, but there is a `VectorBuilder`

Comment: @axel22 that's right I was using the :+ method on Seq, so the same method on Vector does a prepend rather than append, leading to nice performance gains. When I used List I always use the :: prepend method. Scala collections are really good, but sometimes these small inconsistencies are difficult to spot. Thanks v.much

Comment: @RichardTodd `:+` on `Vector` does append as it should, no inconsistencies there. The performance gain comes from the way a `Vector` is structured. It supports both prepend `+:` and append `:+` in effectively constant time.

Comment: Right -- `+:` is prepend for all collections and `:+` is append for all collections. Lists have a special name for `+:` and that is `::`, which is efficient, but their `:+` is inefficient. Vectors strike a middle ground, having logarithmic complexity for both `+:` and `:+`.

Comment: Similarly, if you gradually accumulate sequences using `all ++= more`, you have to change those to `:::`, more specifically, either as `all = more ::: all` or equivalently `all = all.:::(more)` (while `all = all ::: more` is also dreadfully slow)

Comment: Note that `:::` will always copy one of the input lists. The `::` will not copy the input list used for the tail.

Comment: So is there any way to avoid copying one list when you need to concatenate two of them, one of which is about to be discarded? Seems to me it should be possible in constant time.

Comment: It's possible in O(1) time if the lists are mutable linked lists, as is the case with the now-deprecated `LinkedList` collection. But the collections API does not support such a method, I think (and `LinkedList` was anyway deprecated). The only remaining list-ish mutable collection (that I know of) that does what you suggest is `UnrolledBuffer`: https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/v2.12.8/src/library/scala/collection/mutable/UnrolledBuffer.scala#L1

(see `concat` method)

For immutable sequences, more efficient data structures such as conc-lists or `Vector` concatenate in `O(log n)` time.

Comment: Also there are lazy immutable finger tree variants that concatenate in O(1) time (I think there was a paper from Tarjan on that, and maybe another one by Hinze). But, these are quite complex to implement, and the complexity affects their constant factors (at least in the implementation that they describe).

Comment: "should be possible in constant time" said I... if the library would somehow know that none of the list nodes are shared. And the fact that a list is copied shouldn't surprise me, because that also happens when you append it to a mutable collection, I think. Anyways, in my case, making stuff immutable ended up slightly improving performance (with the hope of improving more).